# Facebook4j: How to get total number of likes, comments and shares on a facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook4j

I am trying to retrieve all the essential information regarding facebook posts using facebook4j.

Here is my code:

```
    final Reading reading1 = new Reading().since("-1 month").limit(38).fields("comments", "likes", "id", "message", "caption", "description", "created_time", "from").summary(); 
    final ResponseList<Post> feeds1 = facebook.getPosts("viratkohli", reading1);

    final Reading reading2 = new Reading().since("-1 month").fields("likes", "id", "message", "created_time", "from", "story").limit(100).summary(); 
    final ResponseList<Post> feeds2 = facebook.getPosts("viratkohli", reading2);



    for (int i = 0; i < feeds2.size(); i++) {
        // Get post.
        Post post1 = feeds2.get(i);
        // Get (string) message.
        String message = post1.getMessage();
        Date d = post1.getCreatedTime();
        String id = post1.getId();
       PagableList<Like> pl = post1.getLikes();
       String story = post1.getStory();

       System.out.println("post: "+i+": "+message);
       System.out.println("Created time: "+d.toString());
       System.out.println("id: "+id);
       System.out.println("story: "+story);
       System.out.println();
       for(Like like: pl) {
           String like_name = like.getName();
           String like_id = like.getId();

           System.out.println("like name: "+like_name);
           System.out.println("like id: "+like_id);
           System.out.println();
       }
       System.out.println("******************");

    }

        for(int j=0;j<feeds1.size();j++){
            Post post2 = feeds1.get(j);
            System.out.println(j);
            final PagableList<Comment> comments = post2.getComments();
            for(int k=0; k<comments.size(); k++) {
                // Get comment.
                Comment comment = comments.get(k);
                String id2 = comment.getId();
                String comm = comment.getMessage();
                Date d2 = comment.getCreatedTime();
                Integer co = comment.getLikeCount();

                System.out.println("Comment "+k+": "+comm);
                System.out.println("id: "+id2);
                System.out.println("created time: "+d2);

                }

            System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
            }
```

Currently, I'm able to get the following info:

max. of 100 recent posts, 25 recent likes, 25 recent comments for each post (for max. of 40 posts).

Any help on overcoming the limit issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the total number of likes, but not the individual likes - then set `limit` to 0, and `summary` to 1.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/likes#read

Comment: I followed what you said. When you set limit to 0, you'll get nothing. So I didn't use limit property(by default, it's set to 25). I called sharesCount() method. I got the proper count values. The problem is with likes and comment counts. Take a look at these values from the response JSON array: fields=likes,shares&summary=true&limit=25 sharesCount=105, likes=PagableListImpl{count=null}. The likes count value is null. Can you please help me on getting the proper value? If I missed something, you can tell me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course you get data with a limit of 0 (one the likes of course, not on the feed itself), when you have summary set to 1: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=Facebook%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Did%2Cmessage%2Clikes.limit(0).summary(1)&version=v2.6

Comment: likes and comments have separate Json arrays inside the the post's Json array in which both have count value as null and summary as null. it shows only limited number of people who liked or commented on it (id and name of person). Can you please share the code snippet of getting the counts? It could help me better. Thank you.

Comment: Check the link in my previous comment - that live example in Graph API Explorer shows how it works.

Comment: Ya. I saw it. it's a query. But i needed the programming way of doing it. I did it by examining the array and making some changes. now I'm getting the counts. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right answer:

```
    final Reading reading = new Reading().summary().fields("id", "message", "likes.summary(true)", "shares", "comments.summary(true)").limit(20).since("-1 month"); 
    final ResponseList<Post> feeds = facebook.getPosts("green", reading);

    for (int i = 0; i < feeds.size(); i++) {
        // Get post.
        Post post = feeds.get(i);

       Integer likesCount = post.getLikes().getSummary().getTotalCount();
        Integer sharesCount = post.getSharesCount();
       Integer commentsCount = post.getComments().getSummary().getTotalCount();

       if(sharesCount == null)
           sharesCount = 0;
       if(likesCount == null)
           likesCount = 0;
       if(CommentsCount == null)
           commentsCount = 0;
        System.out.println("No. of shares for post "+i+": "+sharesCount);
        System.out.println("No. of likes for post "+i+": "+likesCount);
        System.out.println("No. of comments for post"+i+": "+commentsCount);
        System.out.println();
```